# Not able to update multiple Update Definitions into the MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to update ErrorMessage field which is under ResolvedItems, but I am getting an error MongoDB driver : Expression not supported.
I tried the below code which is working if I am setting a field like BundleName. But with ErrorMessage not able to do so as its at multiple places and also I am not sure whether this linq has an issue or not.

```
MongoDB Collection :

     {
           "_id" : 
            {
              "$oid": "97368836hsh987"
              },
              "Type": "DataModel",
              "BundleId": "4587654",
              "BundleName": "Work_Bundle"
              "Collection": 
              {
                "Items":[
                {
                "_id": "3046",
                "ResolvedItems":[
                {
                "_id":"45687",
                "Url": "abc@xyz.com",
                "ErrorMessage": ""
                },
                {
                "_id":"4789",
                "Url": "def@xyz.com",
                "ErrorMessage": ""
                },
                {
                "_id":"9874",
                "Url": "ghi@xyz.com",
                "ErrorMessage": ""
                }
                ]
                }
                ]
              }
        }

My C# Code to update DB :

        List<UpdateDefinition<DataModel>> updateDefinitions = new ();
        foreach(string urlItem in liUrl)
        {
        updateDefinition = Builders<DataModel>.Update.Set( p=> p.Collection.Items.SelectMany(item => item.ResolvedItems.Where(resItem => resItem.Url.Equals(urlItem)).SelectMany(x=>x.ErrorMessage)), "ErrorMessage");
        }
        
        await DbConnection.UpdateByKey("BundleId","4587654", Builders<DatModel>.Update.Combine(updateDefinitions)); 


Updated Code to Try again:

foreach(var url in allowedUrlList)
{
  FieldDefinition<DatModel, string> field1 = "Collection.Items.$[].ResolvedItems.$[].Url";
  var filterDefinition = Builders<DataModel>.Filter.Eq(field1, url);
  
  FieldDefinition<DatModel, string> field2 = "Collection.Items.$[].ResolvedItems.$[].ErrorMessage";
  var updateDefinition = Builders<DataModel>.Update.Set(field2, "message");
    
  await DbConnection.UpdateByKey("BundleId","4587654", filterDefinition, updateDefinition); 

}

The above code is working partially when I am not using filterDefinition and its updating all the fields of the ErrorMessage but when I am adding filterDefinition, it does not update anything.
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB .NET Driver version 2.16 and above, it supports [positional operator](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4084?jql=project%20%3D%20CSHARP%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%202.16.0%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20ASC) with `LinqProvider.V3`.

Pre-requisites: You need to enable `LinqProvider.V3` in `MongoClientSettings`.

```cs
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(
    /* MongoDB Connection string */
);
settings.LinqProvider = MongoDB.Driver.Linq.LinqProvider.V3;

MongoClient _client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

```cs
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

UpdateDefinition<DataModel> updateDefinition = Builders<DataModel>.Update
    .Set(p => p.Collection
        .Items.AllElements()
        .ResolvedItems.AllMatchingElements("ri")
        .ErrorMessage, "ErrorMessage");

List<ArrayFilterDefinition> arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>
{
    new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<Item>
    (
        new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "ri.Url", new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "$in", BsonArray.Create(liUrl) }
                }
            }
        }
    )
};

UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions
{
    ArrayFilters = arrayFilters
};

UpdateResult result = await _collection.UpdateOneAsync(x => x.BundleId == "4587654",
    updateDefinition,
    updateOptions);
```

If you are using the version before 2.16, the LINQ way seems hard to implement, instead, you should provide the update key with the positional operator.

```cs
UpdateDefinition<DataModel> updateDefinition = Builders<DataModel>.Update
    .Set("Collection.Items.$[].ResolvedItems.$[ri].ErrorMessage", "ErrorMessage");
```

*Replace the `updateDefinition` variable in the approach for version 2.16 and above.*

For MongoDB query:

```
db.collection.update({
  "BundleId": "4587654"
},
{
  $set: {
    "Collection.Items.$[].ResolvedItems.$[ri].ErrorMessage": "ErrorMessage"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "ri.Url": {
        $in: [
          "abc@xyz.com",
          "def@xyz.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: actually I tried but in updatedefinition linq query, its throwing an error with serialization issue with AllMatchingElement().

Comment: Which MongoDB version you used? Will be great if you can attach the complete exception message.